# Xamarin MainStoryBoard opening error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying xamarin how to create native ios apps with visual studio, but when i open main.storyboard, there is an error

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: did you install the iOS SDK?

Comment: @HeisenBerg seem not yet, where can i download and install?

Comment: I use visual studio 2015 which is downloaded from xamarin site.

Comment: Here's a quick video on how to do it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAAG6KqngtI

Comment: that i 've already installed

Comment: Are you connected to a Mac build host? Also see: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/#Development_Environments